# React redux keep track of state in async API

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, redux, react-redux

I have a react - redux application. Basically, it is similar to a students management app where I list all the students as a table and on clicking any student name, I display the information about the student.

Here is an overview of how my store looks like.

```
{
   students: [
      student1: {
         marks: 100,
         attendance: 70,
         prevMarks: 80
      },
      student2: {
         marks: 50,
         attendance: 70,
         prevMarks: 60
      },
     
   ],
   currentStudent: 'student1'
}
```

As you could see, I have a list of `students` which has the user data and `currentStudent` has the value of the current student for which actions are carried out.

When a student name is clicked, `currentStudent` value gets updated and the value of the `currentStudent` in `students` list is displayed. The thing is `prevMarks` value is fetched using another API call in the background when a student is clicked and the `prevMarks` of `currentStudent` in the store is updated by its response.
I need this API to be async as this should not affect the user to check info of another student

The issue is when the user clicks on `student1` an API call is made to fetch `prevMarks` of `student1` and before the API is completed if the user clicks on `student2`, the response of the API updates the value of `currentStudent` which is `student2`.

Since the response of the API doesn't have the student's name, it is not possible to track the student name based on the response of the API.

How do I track for which student the API call has been made through redux so that I can update the state accordingly? Is it possible to get the `currentStudent` value when the API has been invoked? Is it possible to use `redux-thunk` for this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you change the content of the JSON in the back end? The API that your app consumes is external to your project? If not, you can send more student data in the JSON or the student's id, and then when selecting the student when he is clicked on, make the query filtering by the data sent or by the id.

Comment: @LeandroL Yes. That is an external API, it is not possible to change the contracts of that

Comment: What you say about the response time and the actions of the user is something relative, because the example that you expose may or not happen, it occurs to me that you make a list of requests and associate the currentStudent, that is, create a list where you will save all the currentStudents clicked, then make requests by passing the currentStudent parameter, and save their response, then go through the list and show the total results.

Comment: The other thing you can do is disable the option to select another student while executing the call to the api once another one is clicked.

Comment: @LeandroL Disabling selecting another student while the API call is in progress disrupts the UX and it will b e bad for the end user